# Apache Shiro authcBasic authentication using Java and apache HttpClient

Tags: java, rest, httpclient, shiro

My REST application uses Shiro basic authentication to secure the REST endpoints and its working great when tested from the Browser.

Now I want to be able to login into the application from a java client using Apache HttpClient

Any ideas?

Thank You

Comment: Do you want to connect rest webservice through apache http client with the help of java code ?

Comment: No, I want to login into an application which requires form based authentication from Java

Comment: Ok got your point. Intresting....

Comment: HttpClient has great documentation, including how to do authentication. Have a look here http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/authentication.html

Comment: I'm confused - are you using authcBasic or form-based authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {

        httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
            new AuthScope("localhost", 9009),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password*"));

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost:9009/path/list");

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        System.out.println("executing request" + httpget.getRequestLine());

        String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(responseBody);
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Job Done!");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Command.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java URL with Authenticator

Hereunder an example using Java URL to access SVN http repository using basic authentification:

```
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Omar MEBARKI
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class URLConfiguration {
    private URL configURL;

    public URLConfiguration(final String login, final String password, String httpURL) throws Exception {
        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                   return new PasswordAuthentication(login, password.toCharArray());
            }
        });
        this.configURL = new URL(httpURL);
    }

    public Properties getConfiguration() throws Exception {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(configURL.openStream());
            return props;
        }

}
```